# Filter 2d-list(?) in R

Tags: r

I have this data structure in R:

```
>my2dlist
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.8911965 -0.5783678  1.125074 0.8213261  1.327800
[2,] 0.6354067  1.9959153 -0.571080 0.9250592 -1.668552
```

I want only those element where [1,] > [2,] but can't figure out how to do it, using Filter()

To clarify what I'm trying to do: in python:

```
[x for x in my2dlist if x[0]>x[1]]
```

Comment: Looks like a `matrix` `my2dlist[my2dlist[,1] > my2dlist[,2],, drop = FALSE]` if you are subsetting columns then `my2dlist[,my2dlist[1,] > my2dlist[2,], drop = FALSE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `my2dlist` is a `matrix`, we create a logical `vector` by comparing the first row with the second and subset the columns based on the logical vector

```
my2dlist[,my2dlist[1,] > my2dlist[2,], drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: what does ```drop = FALSE``` do?

Comment: @JMC When there is only a single row or column in the subset, it prevents from dropping the dimensions to a vector